# What does "200 connection established" HTTP response status code mean?

Tags: ajax, http, firefox, xmlhttprequest, http-status-codes

I know about 200 **OK** but what is 200 **connection established**?

To give some background, I am testing out XMLHTTPRequest in an old firefox browser(version 26 to be exact) and I see this as the response code. I am not able to view either the response headers or body so there definitely seems to be some issue. In newer browsers I see 200 OK and there are no issues with the response. I want to understand what this response code means so that I can debug.

In addition I would like to know if this code indicate a problem with the client or server?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The status code is just "200". What follows is the "reason phrase", and it's up to the server to make one up. Note that in HTTP/2 and /3, there is no reason phrase at all.

So; just ignore it.